# How to generate result as the figure title along with filename connected with the plotted image?

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, jupyter

I need help please, to bring the test results and the file name together as the title over the image that is evaluated. I can generate the test results as a list (see image), I can add the test results over the image. I can add the file name over the top of the image. But, I cannot do both. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Thank you.
[image]

```
path = '/Users/minny/Desktop/A/png/file2/'
ref_images = glob.iglob(path + "*.png")  
all_ref_images = []  



for ref_path in ref_images:  
    ref_head, tail = os.path.splitext(ref_path) 
    image1 = Image.open(ref_path) 
    imgA= print(calculate_brightness(image1))
    #all_ref_images.append([imgA, ref_head])    
    ref_image = plt.imshow(image1)
    fig = plt.figure()
    
    
    plt.title(os.path.basename(ref_head)), plt.title(calculate_brightness(image1))
    
    
    #plt.axis("off")
```

```
def calculate_brightness(image):
greyscale_image = image.convert('L')
histogram = greyscale_image.histogram()
pixels = sum(histogram)
brightness = scale = len(histogram)

for index in range(0, scale):
    ratio = histogram[index] / pixels
    brightness += ratio * (-scale + index)

return 1 if brightness == 255 else brightness / scale

%%capture

 #gives a standard size image to view inline with the text
 def display_img(img, cmap=None):
     fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3,3))
     ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
     ax.imshow(img, cmap)
 

 path = '/Users/minny/Desktop/A/png/file2/'
 ref_images = glob.iglob(path + "*.png")  
 all_ref_images = []  

for ref_path in ref_images:  
    ref_head, tail = os.path.splitext(ref_path) 
    image1 = Image.open(ref_path) 
    imgA= print(calculate_brightness(image1))
    all_ref_images.append([imgB, ref_head])               
    fig = plt.figure()      
    ref_image = plt.imshow(image1)
    print(os.path.basename(ref_head))        
    #plt.axis("off")

    ref_image = plt.imshow(image1)
    image_basename = os.path.basename(ref_head)
    title = '\n'.join([image_basename, str(calculate_brightness(image1))])
    plt.title(title, loc='left')

    dir_name = '/Users/minny/Desktop/A/png/results/'
    plt.savefig('{dir_name}/{filename}'.format(dir_name=dir_name, filename=image_basename))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate basename of image's path with output of calculate_brightness function and set result as title without overwriting them:

```
ref_image = plt.imshow(image1)
image_basename = os.path.basename(ref_head)
test_results = '\n'.join(map(str, calculate_brightness(image1)))
title = '\n'.join([image_basename, test_results])
plt.title(title, loc='left')
```

**UPD**:
If result of calculate_brightness function is a float number, you can solve your problem by this way:

```
ref_image = plt.imshow(image1)
image_basename = os.path.basename(ref_head)
title = '\n'.join([image_basename, str(calculate_brightness(image1))])
plt.title(title, loc='left')
```

**UPD2:**
For saving images to specified folder you can use plt.savefig method:

```
dir_name = '/Users/minny/Desktop/A/png/file2/some_directory' # create directory if necessary
plt.savefig('{dir_name}/{filename}'.format(dir_name=dir_name, filename=image_basename))
```

Comment: '''---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-b35e06297403> in <module>
      1 ref_image = plt.imshow(image1)
      2 image_basename = os.path.basename(ref_head)
----> 3 test_results = '\n'.join(map(str, calculate_brightness(image1)))
      4 title = '\n'.join([image_basename, test_results])
      5 plt.title(title, loc='left')

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: It seems that your calculate_brightness function return float value instead of list of float values. Please take a look at update section.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your reply. I tried and it said it was TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable. I was thinking about posting all of the code maybe my mistake is higher up.

Comment: Awesome. That worked. Thank you. Is it possible to see all of the samples in the folder with the image and the label please? Only one came up.

Comment: for saving image to specified directory (dir_name = '/Users/minny/Desktop/A/png/file2/some_folder' for example) you can use plt.savefig('{dir_name}/{filename}'.format(dir_name=dir_name, filename=image_basename))

Comment: I posted the all of the code, but I think I made a mess of the formatting.

Comment: I checked saving by my own and it works well. Maybe you need to tune some parameters of savefig function (f.e. dpi or another one). Also you can ask another question on SO related to this problem. If answer to title question was usefull for you, please approve answer to help other SO visitors to identify correct problem solving.

Comment: I went back and retyped the code correctly. See above. So now it populates. I will work on the file saving part.

Comment: Thank you for being so responsive. It is very much appreciated.